# git fetch prune is not working

Tags: git, fetch, git-remote

I have a bunch of remote branches that were deleted and now I want to remove the branches locally. I've tried:

`git fetch -p`

but it does not work.

If I do:

`git branch -r`

and

`git branch`

the lists are not the same because `git branch` still lists deleted remote branches, even after I run `git fetch -p`. I've seen this as the accepted answer to do this in quite a few questions on here, but it isn't working for me.

I'm not sure I've worded the problem correctly so here's another explanation. Say I have:

> GitHub:  (remote)
>     Branch A
>     Branch B
>     Branch C
>
> Local:
>     Branch A ==> (remote) Branch A
>     Branch B ==> (remote) Branch B
>     Branch C ==> (remote) Branch C

Now somebody deletes a branch on GitHub, giving:

> GitHub:  (remote)
>     Branch A
>     Branch C

What I want my local repo to look like is:

> Local:
>     Branch A ==> (remote) Branch A
>     Branch C ==> (remote) Branch C

Comment: Are you fetching from the correct remote? Assuming `origin`, try `git fetch -p origin`.

Comment: If `git branch` (without `-r`) lists them, they're not remote branches.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To expand on [hobbs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317574/git-fetch-prune-is-not-working#comment32133981_21317574), `git fetch -p` (or `git remote prune` or any similar command) only deletes, from your repository, each "remote branch" that is no longer present on the remote.

If you've made a *local* branch, that label won't go away unless you delete it manually.

For instance, suppose on remote `origin`, there was a branch named `sparkly`:

```
$ git fetch
...
 * [new branch]      sparkly    -> origin/sparkly
```

You don't have a branch named `sparkly` at this point (unless you already had one!); you *only* have `origin/sparkly` (which lives in a separate name-space, `refs/remotes/` rather than `refs/heads/`).

If you created your own branch named `sparkly` earlier, it probably does not track this new `origin/sparkly`.  If you create your own branch named `sparkly` *now*, though, it will track `origin/sparkly`.

In both cases, though, nothing will delete it automatically.  You have to do that manually.

One reason why: there's no guarantee that just because `origin/sparkly` has gone away, *you* are done with it ("it" being the local branch you created, which may or may not track this remote branch).  If git deleted your label along with the `origin/` version, any commits you had been working on might become very hard to find.

So, the short answer is: you'll have to do this manually (or semi-manually, you could automate it as much as you like).  Use:

```
git branch -d sparkly
```

to delete it only if that's "safe" (in git's opinion :-) ), or:

```
git branch -D sparkly
```

to delete it even if git thinks this is "unsafe".

Answer (score 8):

To "forget" locally, removed remote branches you could do

```
git remote prune myRemote
```

---

(Edit to take the comment into account)

Now, to delete your local branches as well you could do

```
remote=origin

for branch in $(git branch | sed 's/\*//'); do                          
  if [ -z "$(git branch --all | grep $remote | grep $branch)" ]; then   
    git branch -D $branch  
  fi                                                                    
done
```

If you plan to do this kind of manipulation often, you could put this in a script in your `PATH`, call it `git-delete-local-to-sync`, and then, in your repo, just type `git delete-local-to-sync`